# Evaluating the following integral from $\pi/6$ to $\pi/2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fractions, substitution

I've been trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$I = \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^{1/3} x}{\sin^{1/3} x + \cos^{1/3} x}\, dx$$

The integral is proper in the given interval and thus converging.
I've tried the following method:
$$I = \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan^{1/3} x}{\tan^{1/3} x + 1}\, dx$$
Substituting $\tan^{1/3} x + 1 = t$, evaluating, followed by $t-1= w$ the integral becomes
$$I = \int_{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}6]{1/3}}^{\infty} \frac{3 w^3}{(1+w)(1 + w^6)}\, dw$$

Please suggest how to proceed further.

Comment: I know that from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ however we have something slightly different. Using symmetry we can say $$I=\frac{\pi}{4}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\tan x}}{\sqrt[3]{\tan x}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$, beyond that I am uncertain how to proceed aside from doing the nasty partial fractions suggested already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, use
$$\frac{u^3}{(u+1)(u^6+1)}=\frac{2u^3-u^2-u+2}{3(u^4-u^2+1)}-\frac{u+1}{6(u^2+1)}-\frac{1}{2(u+1)}$$
and $$u^4-u^2+1=(u^2+1)^2-3u^2=(u^2-\sqrt3u+1)(u^2+\sqrt3u+1).$$

Comment: Thanks for the help and quick response :). I'm feeling bad that I didn't try partial fractions (in lieu of some "trick").

Answer (score 2):

from $$\int \frac{\tan(x)^{1/3}}{\tan(x)^{1/3}+1}dx$$ we get with
$$\tan(x)^{1/3}+1=t$$ :
$$dt=\frac{1}{3}\tan(x)^{-2/3}(1+\tan^2(x))dx$$ where $$\tan(x)=(t-1)^3$$